# How can I run a GitHub Actions job based on a complex condition (specific label removed)?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two reusable workflows to deploy and destroy GCP resources, which I call from one workflow based on different conditions.

One workflow creates infra and is triggered when the label `preview` is added to a PR:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened, labeled]

jobs:
  create-infrastructure:
    if: ${{ contains( github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'preview') }}
    # Call to a reusable workflow here
```

The second workflow I need to trigger when the PR is closed or when a specific label is removed; I tried this:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ closed, unlabeled ]

jobs:
  destroy_preview:
    if: ${{ contains( github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'preview') }}
    uses: myrepo/.github/workflows/preview-app-destroy.yml@v0.3.6
    with:
      project_id: xxx
```

I don't know how to define `unlabeled` for a specific label. It would be great if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pull request webhook payload](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request) doesn't contain the removed label, as far as I can tell, but you can fetch the [list of issue events](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/events#list-issue-events) (which work for pull requests, too), filter by `unlabeled` events, and then look at the label name of the last one.

Using the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli) in a `run` step, that might look something like this:

```yaml
name: Preview removed workflow

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - unlabeled

jobs:
  destroy_preview:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Check if "preview" was removed
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        run: |
          pr=${{ github.event.number }}
          label=$(gh api "repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/issues/$pr/events" \
              --jq 'map(select(.event == "unlabeled"))[-1].label.name')

          if [[ $label == 'preview' ]]; then
              echo "The 'preview' label has been removed"
          fi
```

where you'd replace the `echo` with your infrastructure commands.

---

Now, if you want to call a *reusable workflow* when that specific label is removed, you have to somehow find a way to add a condition to the job where the reusable workflow is called.

One option is to make two jobs, one to check the condition and setting the result as a job output. The other job is set up as depending on the first one, and its `if` condition checks if the output was set to `true`.

This would look something like this (omitting the name and trigger, as they are identical to above):

```yaml
jobs:
  checklabel:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    outputs:
      waspreview: ${{ steps.check.outputs.preview }}
    steps:
      - name: Check if "preview" was removed
        id: check
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        run: |
          pr=${{ github.event.number }}
          label=$(gh api "repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/issues/$pr/events" \
              --jq 'map(select(.event == "unlabeled"))[-1].label.name')

          if [[ $label == 'preview' ]]; then
              echo "::set-output name=preview::true"
          fi

  destroy_preview:
    needs: checklabel
    if: needs.checklabel.outputs.waspreview
    uses: myrepo/.github/workflows/preview-app-destroy.yml@v0.3.6
    with:
      project_id: xxx
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks great. Just not sure how to implement it into my pipeline.

My pipeline calls another workflow:

        ```uses: myrepo/.github/workflows/preview-app-destroy.yml@v0.3.6
             with:
                project_id: xxx
```
Could you please advise how I can combine it together? Very appreciate your comments

Comment: Oh, I see, you're calling a reusable workflow and you're looking for a conditional to make that call or not. I think that can be done with two jobs, let me add that...

Comment: @Olga I have added a solution for that, too. If you're interested, the repo where I tested this is [here](https://github.com/bewuethr/conditionaljob) (for a while, at least), with the workflow of interest [here](https://github.com/bewuethr/conditionaljob/blob/main/.github/workflows/conditionaljob.yml), a run where a "preview" label was removed [here](https://github.com/bewuethr/conditionaljob/actions/runs/2835976321), and a run where another label was removed [here](https://github.com/bewuethr/conditionaljob/actions/runs/2835980001).

Comment: It worked! Awesome! Thank you very much for your prompt and very clear instruction, Benjamin.